# Draw seaborn boxplots

Tags: python, graphics, seaborn, boxplot

I work in an updated version of anaconda and the following code is not working correctly nowadays:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3, figsize=(12, 9))

for idx, feat in  enumerate(features):
    sns.boxplot(x='Churn', y=feat, data=df, ax=axes[idx / 3, idx % 3]) # Axes object to draw the plot onto
    axes[idx / 3, idx % 3].legend()
    axes[idx / 3, idx % 3].set_xlabel('Churn')
    axes[idx / 3, idx % 3].set_ylabel(feat);
```

Something like this should be drawn:

[image]

I don’t understand how to fix my above code, now it only draws boxes, but the graphics inside them are not

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the data from this [link](https://www.kaggle.com/becksddf/churn-in-telecoms-dataset) and seems like the column is "churn" instead of "Churn". You might have renamed the column, so please provide the dataset somehow.

Using the file downloaded, I selected 12 numeric features:

```
df = pd.read_csv("../datasets_2667_4430_bigml_59c28831336c6604c800002a.csv")
features = df.columns[df.dtypes != object][:12]
```

And plot it by flattening the axes:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3, figsize=(12, 9))
axes = axes.flatten()
for idx, feat in  enumerate(features):
    sns.boxplot(x='churn', y=feat, data=df, ax=axes[idx])
    axes[idx].set_xlabel('churn')
    axes[idx].set_ylabel(feat)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @MaxAweTery, since you are new to SO, it would help to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. If this answer has indeed helped you, please consider accepting it. comments with thanks will be deleted.